# Send 3 path to another wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, button, binding

I am newbie of WPF and regardless that I am starting my own project in order to learn more everyday.

Before I ask the question I will explain you what I did so far.

`Mainwindow.xaml` have:

```
"Button" =

private void ModifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win2 = new Window1();
            win2.ShowDialog();
        }
```

`Window1.xaml` have:

```
"image"
"Buttonlink1" "Buttonlink2"
```

Ok that´s all.

What I want do now is this:

From the `Mainwindow.xaml` for the button click of "button" I want send 3 path (variables) for the "image" "buttonlink1" and "Buttonlink2" situated in `Window1.xaml`.

The idea is to have many buttons in the `Mainwindow.xaml` and each one represent a fix for a software error, this buttons will keep different data. 
In the "image" I have to send the path of a `.jpg` that will show an error dialog box. 
In the "buttonlink1" I have to send the path of a `.bat` fix that will fix the issue.
In the "buttonlink2" I have to send the path of a `.bat` that will remotely resolve the issue.

So my question is: How i can send this 3 variables (path) from `Mainwindow.xaml` to `window1.xaml`? and how "image" "buttonlink1" "buttonlink2" will read it and execute it?

Thank you in advance for your help, I am sorry for eventual grammar errors. If something is not clear, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custrom contructor in Window1, which will accept 3 variables, like so:

```
public Window1(String image, String buttonlink1, String buttonlink2)
{
    //Do something
}
```

(As I understand, path is a string?) And then create new object like this:

```
Window1 win2 = new Window1(var1, var2, var3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But when i call Window1 the buttons and the image that i have created previously doesn´t appear anymore.

Comment: You mean, buttons and image which you make in previouse window doesn not appear in Window1? If you realy need to copy buttons from one Form to another, use Panel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

Comment: I see, but i want also keep my Window1 style. Is there a method that would allow me to keep window1 like it is?

Comment: I dont get you... So you want to create new window, which will be exact copy of the parent window?

Comment: Almost, it will have the same style, but this copy of the window, it will have only 2 buttons and 1 image. Do you think is possible?

Comment: You should realy use Panels